# Angular 2 passing ngModel values into directive

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 2 and rc4-
I have a directive and a component, and I want to pass a component's model("list") into directive's model ("dirList").
(Could not post the code due to work issues)

HTML looks like this: (within a form)

```
<div [(ngModel)]="list"></div>
<div dir [dirList]="list" #dir="dir"></div> --- getting the directive's instance and 'dir' is the selector for the director.
```

when using `{{dir}}`,I could see the values of the list on the screen but could not pass the list values into dirList.

code:

```
<div [(ngModel)] ="list"></div> <div dir [dirList]="list" #dir="dir"></div>
```

Any suggestions please?